# Printing non-ascii characters in python/jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, non-ascii-characters

The following code works correctly:

```
from jinja2 import Template

mylist = ['some text \xc3']

template = Template('{{ list }}')

print template.render(list=mylist)
```

When I run it, it outputs:

```
['some text \xc3']
```

Yet, when I try to print the actual list element, it fails:

```
template = Template('{{ list[0] }}')

print template.render(list=mylist)
```

The error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

I would like to find a way to print the individual list element in the same way that the whole list is printed, where the non-ascii character is represented with the \x notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The key is to do `str.encode('string-escape')`

So, I did this:

```
template = Template('{{ list[0].encode("string-escape") }}')
```

And that worked.

Comment: This is a bad approach, you should do any de/encoding before rendering and not delegate this task to the template. And I think `'string-escape'` is probably not the right encoding. What is your original input data?

Comment: The original input data is from an unknown source (web data) and I don't care how it looks when it prints. I just don't want an error in jinja.

As for doing the encoding in the template, I think it's perfectly appropriate since encoding of a string is in the domain of the View, which is what the template is for. Further, I gave a simple example here, however in the actual data the item to be encoded is part of a larger data structure which would take unnecessary processing time to make an additional pass through to pre-encode the values.

Comment: You'll note in the question that I was looking for a way to make it print in the same way as the string prints when I print the entire list object. This solution appears to do exactly that.

Hence, I'd appreciate if you remove the down-vote on my own answer to my question, which I think answered my question ideally. Otherwise, please suggest an alternative solution which I'd be interested in.

Comment: If you fetch web data you should directly encode it at the input step. You can either read the encoding from the HTTP Response Headers and decode it manually or you use a higher level library like `requests` (strongly recommended!) which does this automatically. The problematic point is that for example the char ö will look like `u'\xf6'` if it is printed within list (because there you see the `repr` of the strings). But if you print it as element of this list it should be `ö`. Your approach is just wrong and does not deal with the real cause of your issue, the input.

Comment: Update your question how you actually get your input because this needs to be fixed as real solution then I or others can help you further.

Comment: I disagree. In my specific use-case, I am fetching the data and I am storing it as-is (without any encoding) in a json file. In addition, I need to store it to a user-friendly HTML page for he purpose of the perusal of the client. I have a need to store the original document AND then output the encoded version. It seems very clear that the best way to do this would be the apply the encoding inside the view.

Comment: Storing it without encoding the first place is just wrong because you loose information. Please learn the basics of unicode and encoding, it seems you have a wrong idea from this topic.

Comment: These are web documents. I am using curl to fetch them and save them as files. When I read them, I am not parsing them or making any special attempt to figure out the encoding just so I can print them for this particular output.

Comment: See my answer, didn't fit as comment.

Answer (score 3):

From [Jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#unicode):

"Jinja2 is using Unicode internally which means that you have to pass Unicode objects to the render function or bytestrings that only consist of ASCII characters."

```
mylist = [u'some text \xc3']
```

Comment: in that case how do I convert an non-ascii charcter to ascii ? I have this city name `Al Ghaţghaţ` which I am not able to print in jinja template!

Answer (score 2):

You should never open an encoded file and not decode it.

You should either read the encoding from curl (e.g. with `-i` or `-H` option) and parse the HTTP headers or the output file if the encoding is not specified in the headers.

Or as an alternative to curl you can use the `requests` library which don't require writing to a file. Fetching a web resource will look like:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://python.org')
>>> r.content
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML...
```

Where `content` is already encoded following the HTTP specification.

As an last approach you could guess an encoding and replace unknown chars. This would be the most easy solution to implement. For example:

```
with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as fobj:
    ...
```

Your approach will always loose information (if there are non ascii chars). My first two approaches never and the last one only if the guessed encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

jla is right for my case.

I use utf-8 for the python source files, so use u prefix sovled my problem.