# Django non-ASCII chars in template tags values

Tags: python, django, tags, django-templates, python-unicode

I'm writing a **custom Django template tag** for a french application. My template tag takes a parameter which is a string:

```
{% mytag "Hello" %}
```

Is works perfect, but fails when trying to put some non-ASCII chars in the value.

How would you get this thing work:

```
{% mytag "Êtes-vous à Paris ?" %}
```

I got this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xca' in position 0: ordinal
>   not in range(128)
>
> Unicode error hint
>
> The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Êtes-v

Thanks very much in advance!

EDIT:
Python version is **2.7**. Here is the code of the tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def mytag(context, my_var):
    return "Here it is: {my_var}".format(my_var=my_var)
```

Comment: Which python version? Can you show us the code for the tag?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/13986802/2445183

Comment: Python version is 2.7. Added the tag code in initial post. Thank you for your help…

Comment: Already added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the tags declaration file. Just seems like Django doesn't allow to pass special chars in a tag :(

Comment: @danihp please don't randomly recommend that. Encoding headers are for literals in source code and have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @user650108 you can be sure that that is not the case. Django is fully internationalised and its core developers are from all over the world, including countries with fully non-Latin character sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
return "Here it is: {my_var}".format(my_var=my_var)
```

by

```
return u"Here it is: {my_var}".format(my_var=my_var)
```

In Python 2.7, `"Here it is: {my_var}"` is a `str` object, an encoded string, `my_var` is a `unicode` object, a decoded string, when formatting, Python will try to encode `my_var` so it matches the type of the formatting string. It does so using the [`ascii`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codec by default which does not support special characters.

Adding the `u` before the formatting string makes it a `unicode` string, no encoding will take place during formatting.

Since it looks like you might speak French, I advise you to read [this article](http://sametmax.com/lencoding-en-python-une-bonne-fois-pour-toute/) which is a great guide to encoding in Python.